# Angular 9 update object in array of objects

Tags: typescript, angular9

As the title says I need to update one value in array.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index" >
  <div class="full-w" fxLayout='row' fxLayoutAlign='start center' fxLayoutGap='12px'>
    <span class="title">Color: </span>
    <span>{{item.color}}</span>
  </div>
  <mat-divider class="full-w"> </mat-divider>

  <div *ngFor="let e of item.sizeQuantity; let j = index" fxLayout='row' fxLayoutAlign='space-between center'
    fxLayoutGap='12px'>
    <span class="title">Size: </span>
    <span class="size">{{e.size}}</span>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput type="number" placeholder="Quantity" [value]="e.quantity" #quantity />
    </mat-form-field>

    <button mat-button (click)="updateQuantity(quantity.value, item, i, j)">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the initial data

[image]

and when I enter the data in one field, e.g. under black>xs, it changes on beige>xs too (if there is blue>xs or more it gets updated)

[image]

[image]

I tried several approaches but it keeps updating values at every position

```
  updateQuantity(value, item, ind, j) {

    this.data.forEach(e => {
      if (e.color == item.color) {
        e.sizeQuantity[j].quantity = parseInt(value);
      }
    })
  }
```

Or like this

```
  updateQuantity(value, item, ind, j) {
    this.data.find(e => e.color == item.color).sizeQuantity[j].quantity = parseInt(value); 

  }
```

Am I missing something?

**//EDIT:**

Data is created like this:

```
       let quantity = [];
        let sizeQuantity = [];

        this.selectedSizes.forEach(e => {
          sizeQuantity.push({ size: e, quantity: 0 })
        })

        this.selectedColors.forEach(e => {
          quantity.push({ color: e, sizeQuantity })

        })

        this.dialog.open(AddQuantityComponent, {
          data: quantity
        })
```

where sizes and colors arrays are dynamically created based on user selection:

```
this.selectedColors  = ['black', 'beige', 'blue'];
this.selectedSizes = ['XS', 'S'];
```

Comment: How does the `this.data` get its initial value in `add-quanitity.component.ts`?
I suspect that the initial values of the colors are in one array instance and the colors contain reference to that instance. And as the quantity at one color is updated, the original array is updated and because of this all the colors get the same quantity value.

Comment: this.data is injected as  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data;

Comment: Thank you for the info. How does the origin of the injected data look like?
I'm interested in how the default displayed data is created before it is injected in the component.

Comment: ok check the edit and thanks

Comment: Thank you, see my answer below. In the above code snippet `this.selectedSizes` and `this.selectedColors` are inversely. I assumed in my answer that `this.selectedSizes =['XS', 'S'];` and `this.selectedColors = ['black', 'beige', 'blue'];`.

Comment: yea, you're right, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `quantity` values are updated in each color, because they share the same `sizeQuantity` instance. The problem roots at this method

```
this.selectedColors.forEach(e => {
  quantity.push({ color: e, sizeQuantity })
})
```

Here a deep copy has to be created from the `sizeQuantity`, this means that following could be used:

```
this.selectedColors.forEach(e => {
  let sq = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sizeQuantity));
  quantity.push({ color: e, sizeQuantity: sq });
});
```

It is tricky that JSON serialize/deserialize is used for creating deep copy, but this is the easiest and most backward compatible method. For further details about creating a deep copy check out [this stackoverflow conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).

Comment: Since contents of the `sizeQuantity` are primitive types (string). You don't need a deep clone here. Using the array spread operator or slice method is enough.